# Need help movig DNS providers (ZoneEdit to DynDNS)

Tags: dns-hosting, dyndns, mx-record

I have a domain name and I use GoDaddy as my registar. My DNS provider is ZoneEdit. I'm staying with GoDaddy as my registrar, for now, but I want to switch DNS providers to DnynDNS. I already purchased an account with DynDNS.

In the process of switching, I want to avoid any downtime, especially when it comes to email (MX records). I'm a bit nervous and **I want to double check with someone who has done something like this before that I'm doing things right**. I'm especially interested in someone familiar with DynDNS and Google Apps which is where I host my e-mail. I'm somewhat confused by the priority settings for MX records. **Also, do you suggest simply going to GoDaddy and changing my settings to point to DynDNS or should I do something else to avoid downtime?**

Could you make sure that what I have with ZoneEdit:
[image]

Here is what I have entered into DynDNS:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS MX record priorities are really just what they sound like.  You give each record a priority (the lower the number the higher the priority) and in theory mail servers try the highest priority record first, and if it doesn't respond they try the next one, etc.

I'm a little unsure why you've got records listed from 10 to 70, have a look at this for the relative priorities between the servers - http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=174125

If Zoneedit and Dyn will both be hosting your DNS records (at least for the immediate future) you should be fine, just change the name server delegation at Godaddy and after a while (depending how often the root reloads) you'll see queries will start using the Dyn DNS servers.

It's one of those things that seems a lot scarier than it actually is so long as you do it right.

Comment: thanks for the link to google,the priorities I had were values that I had gotten from some other google FAQ, weird that they suggest such diversity of values.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why is the TTL for your A records only 60 seconds? Make them 3600 seconds like the rest of your DNS records. There's no valid reason to have the TTL so short.
2. Is your domain name a secret? Why black it out? Do you think it's some kind of security risk to let us see what your domain name is?
3. The records you have setup at DynDNS look fine to me (except for the aforementioned TTL of the A records), although I would suggest setting the MX priority to be the same as it's currently set up.

Comment: Not sure why only 60 seconds. Is it just adding extra pressure to the DNS server?